# Find $E'$ and $\text{Int}(E)$ for the set $E = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}{[\frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{2n-1}]} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Find the set of accumulation points, $E'$, and the interior, $\text{Int}(E)$, for the set $E = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}{[\frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{2n-1}]} \subset \mathbb{R}$.

Whats the general procedure to calculate these sets? I am having trouble understanding.

I think that:
$E' = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}{[\frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{2n-1}]} \cup \{0\} $. I am not sure about $\text{Int}(E)$.

Comment: It's easy to write an open set inside $E$, wonder if it's the largest one.

Comment: Is this a set? What's the meaning of a symbol $[x]$ in this context.

Comment: It's a closed interval in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @johnny133253 then why it has only one element? Usually closed intervals look like this: $[a, b]$

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I fixed it.

Comment: You are right about the derivative of $E$. About the interior, just replace closed sets with open sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $E'$ is correct.

Since $\frac1{2n} \to 0$, we have $0 \in E$.

Also, each $\left[ \frac1{2n} , \frac1{2n-1}\right]$ is a closed set. Hence $\left[ \frac1{2n} , \frac1{2n-1}\right]\subset E$

If $x < 0$, then We can draw an open ball of radius $|x|$ and it is disjoint from $E$. hence it can't be a limit point. Similarly, if $x>1$, we can draw a ball of radius $x-1$.

If $x \in \left(\frac1{2n+1}, \frac1{2n} \right)$, notice that $\left(\frac1{2n+1}, \frac1{2n} \right)$ and $E$ are disjoint, hence $x$ can't be a limit point.

Hence $$E' = \{0\} \cup E$$

Clearly $Int(E) \subset E$, it has to be the largest open set in $E$. The boundary point of an interval can't be included as every open ball about them intersect with the complement set.

$$Int(E) = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac1{2n}, \frac1{2n-1} \right)$$